# Error activating IEntityRepository{SomeEntity} More than one matching bindings are available. Matching bindings

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

Team,
I am stuck with the following error.

Error activating IEntityRepository{SomeEntity}

More than one matching bindings are available.

Matching bindings:

1) binding from IEntityRepository{T} to EntityRepository{T}
  2) binding from IEntityRepository{T} to EntityRepository{T}

Activation path:

2) Injection of dependency IEntityRepository{SomeEntity} into parameter someRepository of constructor of type AccountController
  1) Request for AccountController

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IEntityRepository{SomeEntity} only once.

My NInjectDependencyResolver is as follows.

```
 public class NInjectDependencyResolver : NInjectScope, {
    private readonly IKernel m_Kernel;
    public NInjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel) : base(kernel)
    {
        m_Kernel = kernel;

        // Configure by convention
        m_Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Id2.*.dll").SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces());

     // I tried even the following explicit binding. But exactly same error. // m_Kernel.Bind(typeof(IEntityRepository<>)).To(typeof(EntityRepository<>)).InSingletonScope();

    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NInjectDependencyResolver(m_Kernel);
    }
}


public class NInjectScope : IDependencyScope
{
    protected IResolutionRoot m_ResolutionRoot;
    internal NInjectScope(IResolutionRoot kernel)
    {
        m_ResolutionRoot = kernel;
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = m_ResolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return m_ResolutionRoot.Resolve(request).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = m_ResolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return m_ResolutionRoot.Resolve(request).ToList();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        IDisposable disposable = (IDisposable)m_ResolutionRoot;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();
        m_ResolutionRoot = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the public IDependencyScope BeginScope{} method, Instead of

return new NInjectDependencyResolver(m_Kernel);

If I use

return new **NInjectScope(m_Kernel.BeginBlock());**

its perfectly working.

Got it from [here](http://blog.developers.ba/simple-way-share-container-mvc-web-api/).